# error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support Files in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

i am getting following issue While running an application.but i am stuck at this issue

> error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support Files/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.modulemap': Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “AFNetworking.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Volumes/DATA/Working Projects/demo New/BackUp/21-3/demo/V1/Pods/Target Support Files/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.modulemap, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fae56f2e1c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Please check Screenshot
[issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7mz3.png)

can you please help me to figure out this issue?

Comment: Are you using cocaopods?

Comment: @Hapeki yes i am using cocoapods

Comment: Restarting Xcode worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode might be using another projects project path, even though your project is a new project. Closing Xcode and deleting the xcode preferences from ~/Library/Preferences/ might fix the issue.

Comment: which files to delete from the Preferences? "com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist" , "com.apple.dt.xcodebuild.plist"?

Comment: @PratikShah Run `cd ~/Library/Preferences/` and run `ls -l | grep -i xcode` and it'll list all preference files related to xcode and you can remove those

Answer (score 5):

Check whether it is related to Pod files, if so try installing using **pod install** cmd via terminal.
AFNetworking is related to PodFiles, just **comment out your pod files** and then run **pod install in your terminal** (it will remove the respective files). Now **remove the comment in your pod file** and run **pod install** again.

Comment: How can someone "comment ur pod files?".

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes this issue comes when you left library installation using cocoa pod without completion. 
Hitting command *pod install* worked for me.

Comment: Command from terminal doesn't seem to do anything on its own.  Not sure what you're suggesting.

Comment: Are you installing library using pod? then go to that project through terminal and hit command ''Pod install". Also make sure your pod is upto date

Comment: I cd'd to my project, ran pod install, the pod is up to date. This is the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 4):

For me this issue was raised, when a developer changed the upper and lower case writing of a Pod.

However, this solved the issue for me:

```
rm Podfile.lock
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up preferences, project and rebuild should do the job.

```
close Xcode
cd ~/Library/Preferences/
ls -l | grep -i xcode | xargs rm
open Xcode
shift + cmd + K
cmd + B
```

Comment: When I try this I get "clean failed."  I see this as a set back.

Answer (score 0):

I came with this issue when deleted a pod file. After that I install the pod again.
But encountered the same issue.
Then I followed the following step which worked for me.

1. Deleted the derived data
2. Clean and build the project